# Как зафиксировать вьюпорт на движении анимированного объекта?

Tags: javascript, html, анимация, viewport

Пытаюсь зафиксировать вьюпорт на подвижном объекте, но при приведенной ниже реализации скролл почему то отстает от объекта. Кто-нибудь знает почему? Может есть более толковый способ?

```js
const line = document.querySelector(".line");
const item = document.querySelector(".item");
let rect;

function scroll() {
  rect = item.getBoundingClientRect()
  window.scrollTo(rect.left, rect.top);
  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
  
item.onclick = () => {
  line.style.width = line.offsetWidth * 2 + "px";
  line.style.height = line.offsetHeight * 2 + "px";
  item.style.width = item.offsetWidth * 2 + "px";
  item.style.height = item.offsetHeight * 2 + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  animation: move 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Объясни по русский, что именно ты хочешь реализовать...

Comment: Нужно, что бы при зуме вьюпорт двигался вместе с item. А в приведенной реализации item движется быстрее вьюпорта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то ситуация такая:
в коде `item.getBoundingClientRect()` получает уже отрисованное значение, следовательно у нас уже отрисовался кадр где кружочек ушел, следовательно в следующий только кадр мы подтягиваем окно.

Единственный выход который я вижу это добавить плавность хода окна, тогда дерганье пропадет

```
window.scrollTo({
  left: rect.left,
  top: rect.top,
  behavior: "smooth",
});
```

Пример кода:

```js
const line = document.querySelector(".line");
const item = document.querySelector(".item");
let rect;

function scroll() {
  rect = item.getBoundingClientRect()
  window.scrollTo({
    left: rect.left,
    top: rect.top,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
  
item.onclick = () => {
  line.style.width = line.offsetWidth * 2 + "px";
  line.style.height = line.offsetHeight * 2 + "px";
  item.style.width = item.offsetWidth * 2 + "px";
  item.style.height = item.offsetHeight * 2 + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(scroll);
}
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  animation: move 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```